# Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github, nitrousio

I'm trying to run 
    `heroku run rake db:migrate`
but I continuously get this error message:

> Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

I have seen people say just type in `Git Init`, but when I type in that, I just get

> Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/nitrous/sapp/.git/

Answer (score 0):

to test if it has something to do with your filesystem layout you can just see if the directory which holds your code is from a mounted filesystem, or if some part of your project is split across filesystems.

You can also try setting the environmental variable GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM to 1 and retry the git operation. 
NOTE: Please don't do this as a solution until you understand both how your filesystems are layed out and what the GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM variable does.

on unix it'd be like:

export GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM=1

Note the lack of spaces between the variable, the =, and the 1
-wc